# WordPress 'could not create directory' issue on some virtualhosts when trying to download a theme on Ubuntu Server Apache

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I have two virtualhosts, each are wordpress sites. On one of them, everything works perfectly, I can download all the plugins and themes that I want. What's annoying is the configuration of wordpress on both vhosts are completely identical, but on the other I'm getting this error: 'installation failed, could not create directory' when trying to install themes/plugins. I've tried a few websites which explain adjusting permissions, however this has not fixed it. I think it may be something to do with www:data, but I might just be missing something really obvious.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: it should generate some error in a log check them, so you see what exactly gets wrong https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles

Answer (score 1):

Assuming www-data is the user running the WordPress on the server and that you have the right to modify file/directory permissions, try the following:

```
cd /path/to/wordpress
chown -R www-data:www-data wp-content
chmod -R 755 wp-content
```